# Is there any way to make compulsion to call method1 before calling method2 in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hello this question may be silly.

But still is there any way of implementing prerequisites as a method for another method. I am using Visual studio(may not matter).

Example:

```
 public void method1()
 {
     //Method 1
 }

 public void method2()
 {
      //Should call this only after calling method1
 }
```

Comment: Why not call `method1()` from within? or having a `bool` variable that set to true after `method1` is called and the check this in `method2`?

Comment: Does it needs to called ones? Or always before calling the other.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you can achieve that:

**Code Contracts:**

If you use [Microsoft's Code Contract Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.140).aspx), you can set a flag in `method1` that you can require in `method2`

```
private bool hasRunMethod1 = false;

public void method1()
{
    Contract.Ensures( this.hasRunMethod1 );
    //Method 1
    hasRunMethod1 = true;
}

public void method2()
{
    Contract.Requires( this.hasRunMethod1 );
    //Should call this only after calling method1
}
```

The main advantage of code contracts compared to checking `hasRunMethod1` directly in your code is that the static checker can check the precondition at compile time. To give a hint to the static checker `method1` defines a postcondition with `Ensures`.

**Template methods:**

If you don't want to use code contracts or you can not use them (for example if your version of Visual Studio does not allow it), you can use [the template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). That would probably work only in specific scenarios though:

```
abstract class Base {
    private void method1()
    {
        //Method 1
    }

    private void method2()
    {
        //Method 2
    }

    protected abstract void BetweenMethod1And2();

    public void RunTemplateMethod() {
        method1();
        BetweenMethod1And2();
        method2();
    }
}
```

You need to derive from `Base` and implement `BetweenMethod1And2` for the intermediate code.

**Private Token:**

Another option would be to let `method1` return a token that `method2` needs, but that only it can provide. You would though need to make sure that only `method1` can deliver it, for example with a private implementation of an abstract class:

```
abstract class Token {};

class EncapsulatingClass {
    private class PrivateToken : Token {};

    public Token method1()
    {
        //Method 1
        return new PrivateToken();
    }

    public void method2( Token token )
    {
        if ( ( token as PrivateToken ) == null ) {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        //Method 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing that comes to mind is to execute method1 from method2:

```
public void method1()
{
    //Method 1
}

public void method2()
{
     method1();
     // The rest of method2 code goes here...
}
```

Comment: WHy do you keep `method1` `public`?

Comment: @Sefe: Because there might be a need to call it without calling method2. I can't possibly know that from the question, so I left it public.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested above you can call the second method from within the first method itself. Please note that in case if you want second method to be called only for some specific purposes, you can use conditional operators (if etc..) and make a call to method2 as per your requirements. Hope this will help you.