# c# restrict methods to other methods

Tags: c#, chaining, method-chaining

I have a class that contains several methods eg.:

```
class mySqlTool{

    private string _values, _table, _condition, _result;

    public mySqlTool Select(string values = null){
        //this is REQUIRED
        _values = string.Format("select {0} ", values);
        return this;
    }

    public mySqlTool Update(string table){
        //this is REQUIRED
        _table = table;
        return this;
    }

    public mySqlTool Set(string name, String value){
        //this is REQUIRED
        //handle name and value
        return this;
    }

    public mySqlTool From(string table = null){
        //this is REQUIRED
        _table = table;
        return this;
    }
    public mySqlTool Where(string condition = null){
        //this is OPTIONAL
        _condition = condition;
        return this;
    }
    public string Execute(){
        //this is REQUIRED
        //this is samplecode, of course here is checked if its select or update
        //but to keep it short i erased it

        statement = string.Format("{0} {1}", _values, _table);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_condition))
        {
            statement += string.Format(" where {0}", _condition);
        }
        //do some with statemen and fill result
        return _result;
    }
}
```

now I use this in this chaining way:

```
MySqlTool t = new MySqlTool();
string result = t.Select("a,b,c").From("x").Where("foo=bar").Execute();
```

My VS provides me with available methods when I hit DOT `(.)`.

My problem is, I want to denie to use some methods before other methods have been used eg:

```
MySqlTool.Where().Select().From().Execute();
```

In this case `.C()` should not be callable befor `.A()` was called. So to clarify whats allowed and whats not, here a small list

```
//Allowed
t.Select().From().Execute();
t.Select().From().Where().Execute();
t.Update().Set().Set().Set().Where().Where().Where().Execute();

//not Allowed
t.Select().Where().Execute();
t.Select().Select().Select().From().Execute();
t.From()...
t.Where()...
t.Execute()....
```

I read some about interfaces and also about state but I'm not sure if this is what im searching for.

So my question:

Is this what I want even possible?

If yes, how is this technique called?

Comment: State machine for .net ?

Comment: This technique is called "fluent intreface".

Comment: Not at compilation time, at runtime you might carry a state. Just... Don't.

Comment: Check this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319485/is-there-any-way-to-make-compulsion-to-call-method1-before-calling-method2-in-c/41319589#41319589

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**General description - see end for specific comments**

> Is this what I want even possible?

Not within the same class, no. How would the compiler know what you'd already called? (Imagine you had a method with a parameter of type `Test` - what methods should be available to call on that?) The type system decides what's valid and what's not - so if there are different sets of valid operations, that suggests different types.

What you *can* do is have different types representing the different states, which will only include the appropriate methods for state transitions. So you could have something like this:

```
class Test0 // Initial state
{
    public Test1 A() { ... }
}

class Test1 // After calling A
{
    public Test2 B() { ... }
}

class Test2 // After calling B
{
    // This returns the same type, so you can call B multiple times
    public Test2 B() { ... }

    // This returns the same type, so you can call C multiple times
    public Test2 C() { ... }

    public string DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
Test0 t = new Test0();
string x1 = t.A().B().DoSome();
string x2 = t.A().B().C().DoSome();
string x3 = t.A().B().B().B().C().C().C().DoSome();
```

... but your invalid cases wouldn't compile.

It works, but it's pretty ugly. Without knowing what the methods are meant to achieve, it's hard to suggest anything else - but in many cases a single method with optional parameters may be better, or possibly a builder pattern.

An alternative is to use a single class and validate the calls at execution time instead, of at compile time. That's less helpful when coding, but avoids having a huge mess of types.

Yet another alternative would be to have a single class - and create a single instance - but use interfaces to represent the state. Your class would implement all the interfaces, so it could still just return `this`:

```
interface IStart
{
    IMiddle A();
}

interface IMiddle
{
    IFinal B();
}

interface IFinal
{
    IFinal B();
    IFinal C();
    string DoSomething();
}

class Test : IStart, IMiddle, IFinal
{
    public IMiddle A(string x = null) { return this; }
    public IFinal B(string x = null) { return this; }
    public IFinal C(string x = null) { return this; }
    public string DoSomethign { ... }
}
```

Then you'd have:

```
IStart t = new Test();
string x1 = t.A().B().DoSome();
string x2 = t.A().B().C().DoSome();
string x3 = t.A().B().B().B().C().C().C().DoSome();
```

But this feels pretty wrong to me. I'd expect the `A`, `B` and `C` methods to be effectively changing state in some way - so having separate types would indicate which state is available. In the first example, a `Test0` definitely *doesn't* have the state provided by the `A` call, but a `Test1` *does*... and a `Test2` instance has state provided by `A` and `B`, and possibly `C`.

**Specific example**

For the specific example given, I'd probably just make the constructor handle the *required* information (the table name) and use properties/indexers for the rest. I'd probably separate out a query command from updates:

```
SqlQuery query = new SqlQuery("table")
{
    Columns = { "a", "b", "c" },
    Where = { "foo=bar" } // Not sure how you're parameterizing these
};
```

And:

```
SqlUpdate update = new SqlUpdate("table")
{
    // Which columns to update with which values
    ["a"] = 10,
    ["b"] = 20,
    Where = { "foo=bar" } // Not sure how you're parameterizing these
};
```

In each case there'd be an `Execute` method returning the appropriate results.

Comment: is this still chainable ?

Comment: @Dwza: Did you try it? Why would it not be chainable?

Comment: I just read it and asked... using it this way will take some time to redo my code ^^ I just provided a sample. My source I way larger. I will build a sample programm to test this. Ill be back :D

Comment: @Dwza: Please be considerate of the time of other people. When there's something you clearly *can* easily check for yourself, it's worth doing so. You're asking people to help you: the more you can show that you're willing to do everything you can, the more willing they're likely to be to help with what you *can't* do.

Comment: ill get errors on converting Test1 to Test0. And If I would post my whole source or the relevent parts there is to much explanation needed so this would end up in a closed post with no answers. And I'm saying that because I had this szenario more than once.

Comment: @Dwza: Why would you try to convert `Test1` to `Test0`? (You'll need to fill in the code in the braces appropriately, of course - we have on idea what information is within the instance or how the methods affect that.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131795/discussion-between-dwza-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: Note that I didn't ask for your complete code - that's not required to give more context, more idea of what the `A`, `B` and `C` methods do.

Comment: Please put them in the *question* instead.

Comment: Better now ? :D

Comment: @Dwza: Yes, and will add an example.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I am coming late to the discussion, I was thinking the OP could solve his problem as I did this way: [here](https://repl.it/EyUM/0). While in the C++ world (my background), a variant of that is an acceptable pattern to do this kind of thing, Rather than posting an answer, I prefer an expert's opinion in doing that in C#. Whats wrong with doing that in C#?. I have also posted in your [discussion between dwza and jon skeet](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131795/discussion-between-dwza-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @WhiZTiM: That's basically equivalent to the first part of my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet: ...Shameful of me... I didn't observe that. I fought sleep to skim through Stackoverflow yester night. I guess I wasn't seeing sharp. I just reread your answer now. And I am totally embarrassed with myself...

Comment: @WhiZTiM: Not a problem at all :)